# Why is the Mailgun apiKey not recognised by Heroku?

Tags: heroku, mailgun, mern

I am building a MERN app and I am using Mailgun to verify emails. After deploying to Heroku I get an error:

```
Error: apiKey value must be defined!
```

but I have already defined all the keys on my app and on heroku config variables, like so:

```
const keys = require('../../config/keys');

const mailgun = require('mailgun-js')({ 
    apiKey: keys.MAILGUN_API_KEY, 
    domain: keys.MAILGUN_DOMAIN 
});
```

How can I make heroku recognise the apiKey?

**config/keys.js**

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    module.exports = require('./prod');
} else {
    module.exports = require('./dev');
}
```

Comment: heroku config variable will be injected into process.env but if you have provided the same keys into file then it shouldn't be giving any error.

Comment: if you have provided config vars in heroku then change your code as below:
`const mailgun = require('mailgun-js')({ 
    apiKey: process.env.MAILGUN_API_KEY, 
    domain: process.env.MAILGUN_DOMAIN 
});`

Comment: **Afzaal Ahmad**, thank you for your answer. I used your solution and indeed it worked when I used `heroku local`, but after doing `git push heroku master` and `heroku open` I get the same error.

Comment: did you added config vars into your remote app?

Comment: Yes, and I added this to my project `apiKey: process.env.MAILGUN_API_KEY`. And this should make heroku find the key.  I will update my post with the config files setup.

Comment: if you have added variable in config vars of heroku then they should be available in process.env and if you have keys in your code then you do not have to inject config vars at all. I don't know your code structure, unable to pin point the location of error.